# How to make self-signed certificate code execute only once?

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

### Setup:

I am using Spring-MVC in one of my project. I have to access a URL for which I have to use self-signed certificates. I am using the following code in my `service` to do that and it is all working fine.

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
    @Override
    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
    }
}};

// Install the all-trusting trust manager
try {
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
} catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
    LOGGER.error(e);
}
```

### Problem:

Since this code is in my `service`, it is being executed each time a new request is made via this `service`. Is there a way to make this code execute only once instead of for each request? Some sample with actual code will be really appreciated.

Please comment if any more explanation is required.

Comment: Requesting for slightly larger context of this problem. Where u are calling this code from etc.

Comment: As I said in the question, I am using (Java) Spring-MVC. So I have a UI, which makes Ajax call to the `Controller` which calls the `Service`. And the `Service` has all of this code. Does it help?

Comment: Trusting all certificates is unwise, since ***anyone*** with the right (very widely available) tools can create a certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, for example, put this code into init method of separate Spring bean, it will be executed during startup of your application:

```
@Component
public class TrustManagerConfigurer {
    @PostConstruct
    public void installTrustManager() { ... }
}
```

Alternatively, you can put it into [`ServletContextListener.contextInitialized()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to achieve the same effect.

**See also:**

- [3.9.6 @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations)

Answer (score 0):

Just save that ServletContext somewhere instead of recreating it every time.

You are aware that this code is radically insecure? and that the proper solution to this issue is to import that certificate into your truststore?